# Why can't a double displacement reaction be a redox reaction?

Tags: redox

Why can't a double displacement reaction be a redox reaction?

Answer (score 2):

Oh yes it can, especially when an element is formed.  The reaction

$\ce{NaH + H_2O->NaOH + H_2}$

is a double displacement reaction in which the hydride and hydroxide ions switch partners, and also a redox reaction in which some of the hydrogen changes oxidation states.